# How to implment "Agent Protocol" using agsXMPP

Tags: openfire, agsxmpp

I need to implement "Agent Protocol" mention in (http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0142.html). But I have no idea how to do it. I am using agsXMPP as client and Openfire as server. I need a guideline how can I do this. I need a guide line to implement this. Please help..

Regards

Animesh

Answer (score 0):

It's a long time since this post was made.

OpenFire implements the [Agent protocol](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0142.html) with the [FastPath plugin](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/plugins/fastpath/readme.html).

The XMPP client SparkRef and Spark also implements the agent protocol.

*Note : the Agent protocol or XEP-0142 has been deferred by XMPP standards*